# Trouble with php using quotes, double quotes and backslash

Tags: php

I've been hours trying to figure out how to solve one thing, first I had this that works:

```
echo "<p>$valor[nombre_categoria]
         <input type='button' value='modifica' 
         onclick='location.href=\"mod_cat.php?categ=\""
      ,'</p>\n";
```

And then I tried to send with the link a variable but I can't figure it out how to use the quotes, double quotes and backslashes.

```
echo "<p>$valor[nombre_categoria]<input type='button' value='modifica' 
        onclick='location.href=\"mod_cat.php?categ=".
       $valor[nombre_categoria]."\'</p>\n";
```

I'm sure the solution its easy but I cant figure it out thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$valor['nombre_categoria'] = "hello";

echo "<p>{$valor['nombre_categoria']}
       <input type='button' value='modifica' 
       onclick=\"location.href='mod_cat.php?categ={$valor['nombre_categoria']}'\"></p>\n";
```

or this:

```
echo "<p>".$valor['nombre_categoria']."
       <input type='button' value='modifica' 
              onclick=\"location.href='mod_cat.php?categ=".
              $valor['nombre_categoria']."'\"></p>\n";
```

outputs: (line break added for readability here)

```
<input type="button" value="modifica" 
                     onclick="location.href='mod_cat.php?categ=hello'">
```

Comment: Thanks :D that was very helpful! I really need more practice with coding

Answer (score 0):

When you use double quotes, you have to use { and } :

```
echo "Hello {$foo['bar']}";
```

You can skip { and } if your variable is "simple" :

```
echo "Hello $foo";
```

In my opinion, it's always better to use concat :

```
echo 'Hello '.$foo;
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you break your variables out a quote your array elements

```
echo '<p>' . $valor['nombre_categoria'] . '<input type="button" value="modifica"        onclick="location.href=\'mod_cat.php?categ=' . $valor['nombre_categoria'] . '\'"/></p>' . "\n";
```

Easier to read